# Formik issue: Unable to edit text field in simple form in React app

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am unable to enter any text into a text input field within a plain html form that uses formik to handle changes to the field and to handle submit.

See the issue in action here:
https://formik-plain-form-issue.netlify.app/

I have encountered this issue while working on an app that uses Formik in combination with Redux, Bootstrap and Reactstrap, so I thought the issue may be related to these other libraries. However, a simplified version with a plain form and no state management is also showing a similar behaviour.

Here I am providing the code for the simplified version.

PlainForm component code:

```
// This is a React component
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import './PlainForm.css';

const PlainForm = () => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: '',
        },
        onSubmit: values => {
            alert(`Plain form submitted with name: ${values.name}`);
        },
    });

    return (
        <div className='plain-form-container'>
            <h1>Plain Form</h1>
            <form
                className='baseForm'
                onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
                noValidate
            >
                <label htmlFor='plain-form-name'>Name:</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    id='plain-form-name'
                    className='nameField'
                    placeholder='Enter your name here'
                    value={formik.values.name}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PlainForm;
```

You may see the full code for the test app here:
https://github.com/freenrg/Formik-Plain-Form-Issue

Comment: You need to add `id` and `name` attributes to the `input` element. In your case it would be `id="name"` and `name="name"`. [Formik Tutorial](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial)

Comment: Thanks, @shadow-lad. The requirement seems to be that the name attribute has to match the name of the Formik values property for that input field. In this case name="name" as you suggested. The id attribute does not seem affect this behaviour. although the formik tutorial does say "We pass an id and name HTML attribute that matches the property we defined in initialValues". I will post the answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @shadow-lad in the comments, Formik needs the form field to have id and name matching the key of the property defined for that field in initialValues.

See https://formik.org/docs/tutorial

> If you look carefully at our new code, you’ll notice some patterns and symmetry forming.
>
> - We reuse the same exact change handler function handleChange for each
>   HTML input
> - **We pass an id and name HTML attribute that matches the property we defined in initialValues**
> - We access the field’s value
>   using the same name (email -> formik.values.email)

Therefore, the code should be:

```
// This is a React component
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import './PlainForm.css';

const PlainForm = () => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: '',
        },
        onSubmit: values => {
            alert(`Plain form submitted with name: ${values.name}`);
        },
    });

    return (
        <div className='plain-form-container'>
            <h1>Plain Form</h1>
            <form
                className='baseForm'
                onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
                noValidate
            >
                <label htmlFor='plain-form-name'>Name:</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    id='name'
                    name='name'
                    className='nameField'
                    placeholder='Enter your name here'
                    value={formik.values.name}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PlainForm;
```

I have confirmed this works.